# Using a condition inside a dict comprehension : script problem

Tags: python, loops, conditional-statements

I have a problem with my condition inside my dict

So I have a file 'test ' like that:

```
sp_345_4567 pe_645_4567876  ap_456_45678    pe_645_4556789
sp_345_567  pe_645_45678
pe_645_45678    ap_456_345678
sp_345_56789    ap_456_345
pe_645_45678    ap_456_345678
sp_345_56789    ap_456_345
s45678  f45678  f456789 ap_456_52546135
```

and a dictionary like this :

```
dico = {
    "banana": "sp_345",
    "apple": "ap_456",
    "pear": "pe_645",
}
```

Then I want to make a comparison between the values with my first dictionary called dico and see for example in the number of times the banana key appears in each line (and therefore do it for all the keys of my dictionary) except that the problem is that the values of my dico are not equal to those of my dictionary because they are followed by this pattern'_\w+''

I've tried using a dict comprehension

```
import csv
import re

dico = {
    "banana": "sp_345",
    "apple": "ap_456",
    "pear": "pe_645",
}

with open("test.txt") as file :
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter ='\t')
    for li in reader:
        pattern = re.search(dico["banana"]+"_\w+", str(li))
        if pattern:
            final_dict = {"line" + str(index + 1):
                          {key: line.count(text) for key, text in dico.items()}
                          for index, line in enumerate(reader)}
        print(final_dict)
```

But when I print my final dictionary, it only put 0 for banana ...

```
{'line1': {'banana': 0, 'apple': 0, 'pear': 0},
 'line2': {'banana': 0, 'apple': 0, 'pear': 0},
 'line3': {'banana': 0, 'apple': 0, 'pear': 0},
 'line4': {'banana': 0, 'apple': 0, 'pear': 0},
 'line5': {'banana': 0, 'apple': 0, 'pear': 0},
 'line6': {'banana': 0, 'apple': 0, 'pear': 0}}
```

So yeah, now it looks like a bit more of what I wanted but the occurrences doesn't rise .... :/ Maybe my condition should be inside the dict comprehension ??

Can someone help ?

Comment: As you have discovered, dict (and list) comprehensions are great when they work but are difficult to debug when they don’t - the simplest workaround is very simple - don’t use them, instead write a for loop which TBH isn’t very difficult and is much easier to debug if only by simply printing intermediate values.

Comment: Yeah, but that was the first time I used a dict comprehensions ^^', that's why, even if it's simple, didn't manage to put thi condition in the right way :')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer you question about using a dict comprehension because, like @barny commented, I don't think they're suitable to what you're try to do because it's too complicated and too many things are going on. That said, what I'm posting is code showing how to do it in a fairly succinct, efficient, and *readable* way:

It searches for all of the patterns in each line of the csv file while tallying up the number of matches it finds of each, and then adds that to `final_dict` afterwards.

```
import csv
import re


dico = {
    "banana": "sp_345",
    "apple": "ap_456",
    "pear": "pe_645",
}

patterns = {fruit: (prefix + r'_\w+') for fruit, prefix in dico.items()}
final_dict = {}

with open("test_ids.txt", newline='') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter ='\t')

    for index, li in enumerate(reader, 1):
        li = str(li)
        totals = dict.fromkeys(dico, 0)  # Zero fruit line totals.
        for fruit, pattern in patterns.items():
            matches = re.findall(pattern, li)
            totals[fruit] += len(matches)
        final_dict["line" + str(index)] = totals # Add line totals to final dict.

from pprint import pprint
pprint(final_dict, width=60)
```

Output:

```
{'line1': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'pear': 2},
 'line2': {'apple': 0, 'banana': 1, 'pear': 1},
 'line3': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 0, 'pear': 1},
 'line4': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'pear': 0},
 'line5': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 0, 'pear': 1},
 'line6': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 1, 'pear': 0},
 'line7': {'apple': 1, 'banana': 0, 'pear': 0}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dict comprehension is all right. The only problem that i have found here is with csv reader. It only reads the first line of .txt file, at least in my case, so i did it the classic way, and it all work just fine. I left csv out.

```
import re

dico = {
    "banana": "sp_345",
    "apple": "ap_456",
    "pear": "pe_645",
}

with open("test.txt", "r") as file :
    file = file.readlines()
    for i in file:
        i = i.strip()
        pattern = re.search(dico["banana"]+"_\w+", i)
        if pattern:
            final_dict = {"line" + str(index + 1):
                {key: line.count(text) for key, text in dico.items()}
                for index, line in enumerate(file)}
    print(final_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialise final_dict in the loop:

```
    for li in reader:
        pattern = re.search(dico["banana"]+"_\w+", str(li))
        final_dict = {}
        if pattern:
            final_dict = {"line" + str(index + 1):
                          {key: line.count(text) for key, text in dico.items()}
                          for index, line in enumerate(reader)}
        print(final_dict)
```

Comment: This one didn't worked for me :/ but thanks anyway :)